# Comparing Efficiency of Algorithms

Tags: calculus, algorithms

So I was trying to develop a tool for comparing the efficiency of two algorithms for solving a particular problem. Ideally I wanted my tool to produce a constant that represented the effectiveness of one algorithm over another.

Let the two algorithms have time complexities of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ Where $n \in \Bbb N$, and $f(n), g(n)$ are functions with coefficients of $n$ as 1. Say $g(n)$ is the more **efficient** function. I.e $g(n) =  o(f(n))$

We want to find the efficiency function of $g(n)$ w.r.t $f(n)$.
A basic way of comparing $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ is finding their ratio.
The basic ratio function $r(n) = f(n)/g(n)$.

Express $r(n)$ as a polynomial of the form $n^v$ where $v: v \ge 0, v \in \Bbb R$

The Limit ratio function of $g(n)$ w.r.t $f(n)
R(n) = m$-th derivative of $r(n)$. Where $m = \lceil v\rceil$

It follows that $R(n)$ is a constant.

What do you guys think on my method?

Comment: I have no idea what the sentence "The Limit ratio function of $g(n)$ w.r.t $f(n)
R(n) = m$-th derivative of $r(n)$. Where $m = \lceil v\rceil$" is supposed to mean, but whatever it means, the conclusion you draw is false, since $R(n)$  can be non-constant (for example, take $f(n)=e^n$ and $g(n)=n$).

Comment: You'll have to first express $e^n \over n$ as a polynomial of the form $n^m$. Functions which can't be expressed as polynomials are not amenable to my method. "Limit ratio function" is just a fanciful name. It's basically a function of the basic ratio function that produces a constant. It always produces a constant, provided basic ratio function can be expressed as a polynomial. For functions which can't be expressed as polynomials, I will upon attaiming sufficient mathematical skill, find a way to deal with them

Comment: Yeah, so cases where $r(n)$ is not-polynomial. Any help on how to tweak my function such that it scales? (to exponential, factorial, $n^n$) functions. I'm not sure how my function handles log functions and the inverse ackermann functions.